# Hydraulic disk brakes starts braking after pulling the half of the lever, how can I solve this problem with the brakes?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have upgraded from v brake which starts braking immediately after pulling the brake lever, but in my new bike the brakes starts much later after pulling the lever. What problem it may have? I am using a Tektro branded brakes.

Comment: they need bleeding to get the air out of the system. Type the model number of your brakes into YouTube, along with the word "bleed" and you will likely find a video on how to do it

Comment: Are the brakes mechanical or hydraulic? As PeteH says - if they are hydraulic - the brakes may require bleeding. You can test this by pumping the brake lever and if they stiffen up after several successive pulls on the lever - than they need bleeding. Otherwise, if they are mechanical - then it is a case of cable adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on pad adjustment and most hydraulics have some kind of auto adjustment, also following pads' wearing - small "springs" between the pads return them to the initial position. Cable driven disc brakes can be adjusted at the caliper for tighter fit. 
You'll probably never be able to start braking immediately. It needs some play, otherwise it would always touch the disks.
Though wiht hydraulics you should also check if you have enough oil/brake fluid in the lines, without air in it. That can also cause a loose, weak braking. It's probably done best by a professional.